# MIME Emails - PDF and Content-ID

Tags: email, http-headers, mime

We are sending Emails using The MIME-Format.
(Underlying language is Java, using MultiPartEmail).

It has been reported by customers that their system reads the .pdf-Attachment of our emails twice.

The reason for this is, apparently, the lack of a Content-ID for the attachment.

I'm trying to fix this but found really vague information about the content-ID. Reading the standard i figured it is just supposed to be some unique ID in the form of `<ID@domain>`.

So i added this into our email generation, so that the "slot" which references the .pdf-attachment looks something like this:

```
------=_Part_0_12345667890
Content-Type: application/pdf; 
name=theName.pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
filename=theName.pdf
Content-ID: <1431939868331@domain>
```

Is that all there is about it? The number is current time in milliseconds. 
I'm unclear about the domain. Is it critical that this domain is exactly the right one?

And how can i understand this Content-ID attribute? Is it simply what i think it is: an ID so that attachments can be uniquly referenced by some email-systems or is there more to it? Why is the domain important?

Edit: I don't know if its related, but it seems the .pdf-Attachment doesnt show in the iPhone Mail software. I can't think of any other reason it would not show, as .pdf is surely supported and the files are also quite small. (The icon of an attachment shows in the overview-list but the attachment is nowhere referenced in the opened email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:
Yes, it does the trick for many email services. There just has to be some kind of ID for the elements contained in MIME and then they are rendered and read correctly.